# Remote logical username in Tomcat Access Log Valve pattern

Tags: tomcat

What is the point of having a constant value printed in Tomcat access log files with a special code for it? The Access Log Valve doc says:

> **%l** - Remote logical username from identd (always returns '-').

I have checked the source code looking for an explanation and really it always appends a '-'. Is there a scenario where this value can be useful?

Answer (score 0):

It's a historical holdover in log formatting from the 1990's and when this was geared more toward LAN usage on more trust worthy networks. Aka, good intention, but horrible in reality with respect to security and performance. (Much like other commands like `finger` )